# how i know what is my actual Error occur?

Tags: android, titanium

I build a application in Android & iphone both it work fine. but some time crash in Android and flash the message

> The Application ABC (com.abc.abc) has stopped unexpectedly. Please try
>   again.

how i know what is my Actual Error occur 
any suggestion is appreciated

Comment: Take a look at the logs?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can debug the application using java exception handling and log the run time exceptions. When an exception occurs it can be viewed in DDMS.

```
try{

    // Code comes here

}
   catch(Exception e){
    Log.e("Exception: ", e.toString());
}
```

Comment: actually, when i run my project in Android device or Emulator the first screen is load n after this this flash massage 
~~~
The Application ABC 
(com.abc.abc) has stopped 
unexpectedly. Please try again.
~~~
how i know what is actual problem?

Comment: @Suraj If app is throwing exception at first go, first thing you should check is- if the activity is declared in Android.manifest. But can't say anything without viewing the source code. Post the code of activity which is throwing exception or atleast the catLog.

Answer (score 1):

If you are testing this on an emulator, you can just view the error in LogCat. If it's only occuring on the phone, you can:

**Debug over USB**

Read the android guide on how to setup your device and environment to enable debugging over a USB connection.

http://developer.android.com/guide/developing/device.html

or

**Install a tool to capture errors**

There are tools out there that will capture and save the error on their website (under your account), whenever an error occurs. BugSense is the tool I use, but there is also ACRA (Application Crash Report for Android), which pretty much accomplishes the same goal.

The premise is simple. Download the library for the tool you want to use, add the jar to your build path and configure your application to *allow* those tools to intercept any errors.

I've personally found these tools are invaluable if you're releasing an application to users as it gives your users the ability to send in error logs. I've found my own personal testing of my application has only caught about 50% of the bugs, the rest came from users sending in crash reports with somewhat obscure scenarios I never thought of testing. (Yeah, I know, I'm a bad tester)

[ACRA](http://code.google.com/p/acra/)

[BugSense](http://www.bugsense.com/docs)